# Http GET Request from NodeJS to external API with http.get()

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get-request

I am trying to do an HTTP GET request to an external API with NodeJS (using Express), but I am not getting any data back. My code is the nextone:

```
 import * as http from "http";

const options = {
    host: "EXAMPLE.COM",
    path: "/MY/PATH",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
};

const req = http.get(options, function(res) {
console.log("statusCode: " + res.statusCode);

res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
});

});
```

But the response I get is: 
   **statusCode : 302**  and **BODY** is empty.

The external API works properly (I have tried doing a http GET Request with INSOMNIA and returns data)

The request I am doing **NEEDS** an Authorization Token

What am I doing wrong? or what can I do to get the data back?

Cheers

Comment: have you tried passing like this: `"Authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

Comment: Edited the question. "Authorization" : "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXX"

Comment: You are being redirected to a different location. Follow the redirect. The response will have a `Location:` header.

Comment: thanks for the response Evert. I have checked, and I receive this: 
 https:// **https://EXAMPLE.COM/MY/PATH** (res.headers.location) the same I am inserting.

Comment: Probably you are making the request to ```HTTP://{url}``` and it gives you back ```https://{sameurl}```

Comment: I have changed the http for https, and works properly. Thanks for de response!!

Answer (score -2):

You are just throwing data to console.log and not responding to request.

You did not mention if what http server you are using with node. In case you are using express.js (most common one) you should have something like:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3003;
const http = require("http");
// your webserver url localhost:3003/fetch-something
app.get("/fetch-something", (req, res) => {
  const options = {
    host: "EXAMPLE.COM",
    path: "/MY/PATH",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }
  };

  const httpReq = http.get(options, function(httpRes) {
    //output status code to your console
    console.log("statusCode: " + httpRes.statusCode);

    httpRes.on("data", function(chunk) {
      // still nothing happens on client - this will also just print to server console
      console.log("data", chunk);
      // return some data for requested route
      return res.send(chunk);
    });
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vladimir, first of all I know what does the Console.log, and second I am using express. But I am doing this method (in a Middleware) to check that a data with I am receiving to de app, has a correct Authorization Token (so I am validating it with external API)